# my openConnection() is giving connection refused error

Tags: java, url, connection

I am writing one application which needs to connect to the url specified.I am getting ip address for the url http://gmail.com
When I call openConnection on this url  It is giving connection refused error.I am connected to internet and ran this program.Still getting connection refused error.When I type this url in browser it is giving me the connection to the url.
Can you give me the reason.Since it is giving ip address but not getting connected.I tried similar with google.com also ip address I am getting but not connected to google still getting connection refused.
Please help me
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same User-Agent then your browser.

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1");
```